# How do I respond to the Dropbox webhook challenge in Dark?

Tags: dropbox

I want to respond to a Dropbox webhook using my Dark app (https://darklang.com/)

It says I need to set some headers to respond to the challenge (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/webhooks)

How do I even set headers in the response?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is twofold:

You need to set the correct headers. This is tricky in Dark, especially with headers that have a dash in the name

And, you need to pull the 'challenge' out of the URL parameters and then put that in the body of the request. Try this:

```
let body = request.queryParams.challenge
let headers = Dict::empty
              |>Dict::set "Content-Type" "text/plain"
              |>Dict::set "X-Content-Type-Options" "nosniff"
let response = Http::respondWithHeaders body headers 200
response
```